# How to attach event listener to multiple elements in React (not in-line)?

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener

Instead of having to attach event listener to each element, how can you add event listeners to a group? Consider having multiple input elements. Instead of repeating `onChange={this.handleChange}` how can I just attach this function to onChange for all input elements?

Something that with vanilla JS was as easy as selecting all inputs, looping and attaching.

```
render() {
    return (
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <h1>{this.state.firstName} {this.state.lastName}</h1>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dedicated on-the-fly component, something like:

```
render() {
    const Input = props =>
      <input onChange={ this.handleChange } { ...props } />

    return (
        <form>
            <Input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
            <br />
            <Input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <h1>{this.state.firstName} {this.state.lastName}</h1>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks you. But I am guessing there is no 'vanila js' way of selecting, looping and attaching?

Comment: Nope, this is the React way, it's declarative :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try making your elements that must be subscribed (such as the `inputs` in your code example) into components, creating an array object with them and `.map` over it, passing your `handleChange` function to them.